# Nuxt Js SSR requests fail (only server side) + Docker + axios + Linux

Tags: docker, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, caddy

I'm developing a nuxt js universal ssr app. The depoloyment config is as followed:

- Nuxt js universal app running on a docker container(running on nuxt 3010 port )
- Linux caddy webserver
- Laravel backend running on a seperate docker container
  The server is using reverse proxy to set backend on domain and the etc/hosts file includes backend domain setting it as 127.0.0.1
  **The Problem:**
  Server side requests change the axios base url to http://localhost:3010 (instead of https:api.domain.com/) and result in 404 not found errors or timeouts or even 127.0.0.1 ECONNREFUSED nuxt error. THE SAME REQUESTS WORK FINE on client side and this only happens upon initial loading of the page(the server side rendering of the page)
  Why is the url changing? how should i prevent it from changing base url?
  docker file includes:

```
RUN apt-get update

ENV APP_ROOT /src
ENV DOCKER_API https://api.domain.com

WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
COPY . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./app/
    ports:
      - "3010:3010"
    environment:
      ALI_URL: https://api.domain.com/
    restart: always
    command:
      "npm run start"
```

nuxt server config:

```
server:{   
port:3010
}
```